# Is there a need to set up a class for one or several functions in C++

Tags: c++

I feel confused with whether there is a need to set up a class for one or several functions. I give the following example to make my point clear:

```
file1.h
   void Fun1();
   void Fun2();

file1.cpp
   void Fun1() {}
   void Fun2() {}
```

As you can see we have two functions here, and people using these functions just need to include the header file and then call them. Then, I also have the choice of setting up a class without any member variables insider but only for these two functions (suppose these two functions are closely related):

```
file1.h
   class Operation
   {
      Operation() {};
      ~Operation() {};
      void Fun1();
      void Fun2();

    };
file1.cpp
    void Operation::Fun1() {};
    void Operation::Fun2() {};
```

Then my question is which practice is better and why. Thanks.

Comment: I think you should use a `namespace` instead of a `class`. And if you use a class, at least, set your two functions as static functions.

Comment: If you're not going to manipulate any members and you only have some helper functions, then you shouldn't really create a class for them, there isn't much of a point. Classes are there to represent objects with attributes that you want to manipulate in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a dedicated namespace

file1.h:

```
namespace MyDedicatedNameSpace
{
   void Fun1();
   void Fun2();
}
```

file1.cpp:

```
void MyDedicatedNameSpace::Fun1() {}
void MyDedicatedNameSpace::Fun2() {}
```

Or if you want to use a class, you should set these functions as static:

file1.h:

```
   class Operation
   {
public:
      static void Fun1();
      static void Fun2();
    };
```

file1.cpp:

```
void Operation::Fun1() {};
void Operation::Fun2() {};
```

Answer (score 2):

There should be a reason you want to put them in one class.
If it's just for grouping, **namespace** better suits for this role.

```
file1.h
   namespace Operation
   {
      void Fun1();
      void Fun2();
    };
file1.cpp
   namespace Operation
   {
      void Fun1(){};
      void Fun2(){};
   };
```

P.S. If for some reason you would still prefer to use class, make functions static at least, so you wouldn't need to create an instance of this class.

```
file1.h
   class Operation
   {  
   public:    
      static void Fun1();
      static void Fun2();
    };
file1.cpp
    void Operation::Fun1() {};
    void Operation::Fun2() {};
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't "have to" put them in a class, you can go for both implementations. It's mostly a design preference. Java coders are used to putting those functions as static functions of a utility class, but in C++ you don't have to, although some people do.

If your concern is just encapsulation of those functions in a specific context, you might also consider putting them in [namespaces](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/).

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked specifically about C++, the most correct answer would be to namespace them:

file1.h:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    void Fun1();
    void Fun2();
}
```

file1.cpp:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    void Fun1() {}
    void Fun2() {}
}
```

Then to use them you would simply call `MyNamespace::Fun1()` etc.

As I started out saying, this is most correct for C++.

If you were writing this for C, or mixed C/C++ it should be noted that C does not support namespaces. So in that case making them static functions of a class would be a better organizational route.

file1.h

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    static void Fun1();
    static void Fun2();
};
```

file1.c

```
void MyClass::Fun1() { }
void MyClass::Fun2() { }
```

NOTE: if you are doing mixed programming you should consider making it easier to [include](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/include-c-hdrs-personal.html), but that's beyond the scope of this question.